# Determine if string in input is a single word in Python

Tags: python, string

a brain dead third party program I'm forced to use determines how to treat paths depending if the input supplied is a single word, or a full path: in the former case, the path is interpreted relative to some obscure root directory.

So, given that the input can be a full or relative path, or a single word (including underscores and dashes, but not spaces), I'm wondering how to write a function that determines if the input is a single "word" as defined above.

For example:

- "Public_345" would classify as valid "word"
- "/home/path/to/something" would obviously be not
- "Foo bar" would also not be considered a valid "word"

As string methods are not OK, I am wondering if it would be possible to use regular expression. Initially I thought up of something like this:

```
match = re.compile(r"[\w-]+")
word = "abdcde_-4"
if len(re.findall(match, word)) == 1:
    print "Single word"
```

It does feel extremely ugly, however, and I'm pretty sure it doesn't catch corner cases. Are there (much) better solutions around there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could tweak your regex to match the whole input string so that you don't have to count the matches. I.e.

```
if re.match(r'\A[\w-]+\Z', word):
  print "Single word"
```

(compile the regex if you feel so inclined)

`\A` and `\Z` match the beginning and end of the input string, respectively. So, if your `word` contains other data in it besides the path, then the above approach does not work.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> r="Foo bar".split()
>>> if len(r) != 1: print "not ok"
...
not ok
>>> if "/" in "/home/path/to/something":
...   print "ok"
...
ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the string and see if it contains a `' '` (space) or an `'\'` (path separator). If it does, then it's not a "single word".

Answer (score 0):

Check the os.path module. You can use [os.path.abspath()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) to convert a given path into full path (if it is on the same system).

You can check with the following snippet if the string has any whitespace characters.

if(str.split()[-1] == str) return True